# How to combine different flavors in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

I have developed an application in android with different flavors, and i have updated these two flavors in google play store. Now what i want is to combine these two flavor and build a single apk , So that the combined flavor apk will update these two apks in play store.

My question is -- Is this possible , **to update different flavor apks with single combined flavor apk and if so how to achieve this**

Comment: What is flavor in the apk ?

Comment: A flavor is only a build configuration. An answer to your question solely depends on your implementation. So you should at least post your gradle file. And state more precisely what you intent to do. From what I read the most probable answer is a straight NO.

Comment: @ Nambi Narayanan, I mean builds with different flvor

Answer (score 0):

Each application you create is signed with a keystore that you provide during the release build process. As long as the key that you are using is the same, you can build an APK and use it as an upgrade to your current application.

In addition, the version of the new apk needs to be greater the the version of your current applications. To update the version you need to edit your relevant build gradle file:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
  productFlavors {
    demo {
      ...
      versionName "1.1-demo"
    }
    full {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer to Android Studio documentation for more details: [Version Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: I know that the key , package id and upgraded version is necessary for update, but my question is that i have released two builds one with flavor1 and another with flavor2 with same key and same version code but different application id, now i want to update flavor2 with flavor1 or with combined flavor, Is this possible?